# google/protobuf/timestamp returning empty object

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, backend, grpc, proto

I have a proto file that is supposed to return created_at and updated_at as timestamps and they are saved that way in the DB, but once i send a request i get empty object for both even tho there is a timestamp saved in the DB

proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package user_package.v1;

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message User {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp created_at = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp updated_at = 2;
}
```

DB schema: (mongo)

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  }
});
```

response from DB:

```
[
  {
    createdAt: 2022-06-07T11:51:14.391Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-06-07T11:51:14.391Z,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Response received when calling rpc:

```
"users": [
        {
            "created_at": {},
            "updated_at": {},
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Do you have a gRPC server that is querying the database for those values and returning them to a the client?

Comment: The `Timestamp` message type has a specific format that is not the same as JavaScript's Date class. Are you converting between the two types when you respond to the RPC?

Comment: Yes I have a gRPC server querying the db, they are saved as a timestamp in the db, and the format is in ```year}-{month}-{day}T{hour}:{min}:{sec}[. {frac_sec}]Z``` which is supposed to be compatible with google/protobuf/timestamp.proto

Comment: Have you verified on the gRPC server side that the created and updated are being correctly instantiated before sending to the client?

Comment: they are returned from the DB in the correct format, but when it passes to the proto (where the data type is set to Timestamp) I receive an empty object, that's the issue and i have no clue why